# Tensor Reshape No-op in RNN example

Tags: python, reshape, tensorflow

What exactly is this code doing in the method `zero_state` for the `RNNCell` in the file `rnn_cell.py`? I'm not entirely sure what a shape of the form `[-1, n]` means...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semantics of reshape are similar to the one from numpy:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

It changes the tensor to have 2-dimensions and the second dimension should have self.state_size elements. E.g. if my tensor has 6 elements and I reshape it to [-1, 2], then the first dimension will have 6 / 2 = 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Rafal's example is great.  The way I remember -1 is that it sets the size of that dimension to whatever's necessary to fit all of the data from the original tensor.  You can only have one -1 in a reshape.

If the original tensor is of size a, b, c  (total elements = a*b*c)
and you resize it to x, y, -1,

then the effect will be that the -1 will end up being a*b*c/(y*z).

A 3,3,3 tensor (27 elements) reshaped to 9,3,-1 will actually have a size of 9,3,1 (27 elements)

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation vaguely suggests](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops.md#reshape) the behavior for -1.

> If shape is the special value [-1], then tensor is flattened and the
>   operation outputs a 1-D tensor with all elements of tensor.

When the shape is an array, where one of the elements is -1, this value is just a convenient placeholder for some integer that might produce the same shape. Note that there might not be such an integer (for example if your starting matrix is `[5x5]` you can not reshape it with `[7, -1]`).

Also as you see there can not be two -1, because this make the shape ambiguous. As it was noted, the behavior is similar to [numpy's reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).